# What do you think is the value of $\int_0^{\pi}\cos^nx \,dx$ where n is a positive odd integer?. Prove your conjecture.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

I just simply can't get this one. So, any help will be appreciated.

The question goes like this:

What do you think is the value of $\displaystyle \int_0^{\pi}  \cos^nx \,dx$ where $n$ is a positive odd integer?. Prove your conjecture.

I know the value is $0$, but I just don't know how to prove it. Thank you for your help and time.

Best regards!.

PS: Sorry if it is a duplicate. I have searched everywhere and find no solution/help for this one.

Comment: Maybe try drawing a little picture and figuring out how to split the integral into two parts. You don't even need to integrate.

Answer (score 3):

Substitution:

$$\;x=\frac\pi2-t\implies dt=-dx\implies\int_0^\pi \cos^nx\,dx=-\int_{\pi/2}^{-\pi/2}\cos^n\left(\frac\pi2-t\right)dt=$$

$$=\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\sin^n t\,dt=0$$

since $\;\sin^nt\;$ is an odd function...

Answer (score 1):

Let $I=\int_0^\pi\cos ^nx\,dx $$\tag 1$ 
Use the property: $\int_a^bf(x)\,dx=\int_a^bf(a+b-x)\,dx$ to get:

$I=\int_0^\pi\cos^n(\pi-x)\,dx=-\int_0^\pi\cos^nx\,dx $; since $n$ is odd. $\tag 2$

Add $(1)$ and $(2)$ to get: $2I=\int_0^\pi\cos ^nx\,dx-\int_0^\pi\cos^nx\,dx=0\implies I=0$

Answer (score 0):

This is obvious once you realise that the graph of $\cos^nx$ is the same if you rotate if by $180^\circ$ about the point $(\pi/2,0)$. So all the positive values cancel out exactly with the negative values.

You can try and make this argument more formal, as other posters have done. But I think they are missing the point. (And if you do insist on formalising it, you don't need to integrate any trigonometric functions; you just need to use the fact that if $f(\pi/2-x)=-f(\pi/2+x)$, then $\int_0^\pi f(x)dx=0$.)

Answer (score 0):

Put

$$I_n = \displaystyle \int_{0}^{\pi} \cos^nxdx=\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\pi}\cos^{n-1}xd(\sin x)= - \displaystyle \int_{0}^{\pi}\sin xd(\cos^{n-1}x)=$$

$$ (n-1)\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\pi}\sin^2x\cdot \cos^{n-2}xdx= (n-1)\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\pi}(1-\cos^2 x)\cos^{n-2}xdx=$$

$$(n-1)I_{n-2}-(n-1)I_n\implies I_n = \dfrac{n-1}{n}I_{n-2}= \dfrac{n-1}{n}\cdot \dfrac{n-3}{n-2}I_{n-4}=...=$$

$$=\dfrac{n(n-1)(n-3)\cdots 2}{n(n-2)(n-4)\cdots 3}I_1= 0$$

since $I_1 = \displaystyle \int_{0}^{\pi} \cos xdx = 0$.